# How to replace all non-valid characters in string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How would I go about in replacing every character in a string which are not the following:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_.@-`

with `-`

So for example, the name `Danny D'vito` would become `DannyD-vito`

My inital thought was converting string to char[] and looping through and checking each character, then convert back to string. But my hunch is telling me there must be an easier way to do this

Comment: what happened to th space here `Danny D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regex.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace) approach

```
string input = "Danny D'vito";
string result = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.@-]").Replace(input, "-");
```